# When does a matrix define a convolution operator on a hypergroup?

Tags: pr.probability, fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, harmonic-analysis, hypergroups

Let $H$ be a discrete hypergroup. Suppose I have a matrix $A=(A_{x,y})$ indexed over $H$ with nonnegative entries which defines a bounded operator on $\ell^2(H)$. When does there exist $f\in\ell^1(H)$ such that $A_{x,y}=\langle f*\delta_x,\delta_y\rangle$, i.e., $A$ is the matrix of transition probabilities for a random walk given by convolution with $f$?

A necessary condition is that $A$ commutes with $\ell^1(H)$ convolution on the right. Is this sufficient?

Comment: Presumably then you have an answer to my question as to when and why hypergroups appear in mathematics http://mathoverflow.net/questions/30288/what-are-hypergroups-and-hyperrings-good-for

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In case of discrete groups, it requires amenability of $H$. Indeed, $H$ is amenable if and only if $f\in\ell^1(H)$ for all $f\geq0$ such that $[f(xy^{-1})]_{x,y} \in B(\ell^2H)$. I just don't know what are hypergroups.

Comment: There is a notion of amenability of fusion rings by Izumi and I guess this might be what needed.